# Random Walk, Markov Process

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk

I'm stuck on a homework question and am wondering if anyone can offer some hints.
Suppose we have some straight line graph G over the set $ V = \{1, 2, 3, ... , n\} $ of vertices, with an edge between $u$ and $v$ if and only if $u$ = $v\pm1$

That is it looks like 1 --- 2 --- 3 --- 4 --- ... --- n 
I'm trying to compute the probability $p_{i}$ that starting at node $i$, a random walk hits node $1$ before node $n$. Obviously, $p_1 = 1$ and $p_n = 0$

We've been covering Markov processes in my class, but everything reagrding walks so far has been about the expected hitting time of a node v starting at a node u, and I don't see how to use that here. Computing the hitting time of 1 and n from a node i doesn't allow us to know the probability of reaching one before the other, unless I'm missing something.

So far I've tried using:
$p_i = \frac{p_{i-1}}{2}+\frac{p_{i+1}}{2}$
 but I quickly run into trouble doing this, since you get some messy variant of Pascal's triangle.

I also tried proceeding by induction but can't seem to get anywhere doing that either. Surely there's an elegant approach.

Thanks!

Comment: how about trying to describe it with an absorbing markov chain, where if it reaches either node 1 or node n it stops.  In doing so, if it hits node 1 and stops it should be equivalent to the situation that it hits node 1 and then node n at some later time.

Comment: @JMoravitz I don't see what information I can get out of the above markov chain. I can't get anything out of the stationary distribution, and I run into the issue of the expected hitting time of nodes 1 and n not giving me the probability that we hit either node first.

Comment: By representing the markov chain in its transition matrix representation, $\matrix {I&S\\0&R}$, you can calculate it's longterm/stable matrix $\matrix {I& S(I-R)^{-1}\\0&0}$.  $(I-R)^{-1}$ is the fundamental matrix which gives average stopping time, but the final long term matrix gives chances of arriving at one of the final absorbing states.  Having arrived at one of the absorbing states (node $1$ or $n$) means you have hit that node first before the other.

Comment: "since you get some messy variant of Pascal's triangle" Let me suggest to solve entirely some small $n$ cases--and you will see that calling these "messy" is really unwarranted. The global picture might emerge even more clearly if you consider the walk on {0,1,...,n} and the probability p_i to hit 0 before n starting from i.

Comment: @JMoravitz This seems to make things hugely more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @JMoravitz I ended up solving the problem a couple of ways, are users encouraged to post solutions if they figure their own problem out? I could write up a solution.

Comment: Yes, of course.